# htaccess Redirect 301 problem .. all redirects with one string fail to redirect and 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

So I have moved a website and am trying to 301 redirect everything, which I do quite often so this is a weird problem but probably something stupid I'm not seeing.

ALL of my redirects are working fine, except any redirect that the first string starts with "/Dining" or "/dining" are failing.  For example, this redirect works fine-

```
Redirect 301 /healthfitness/teeth.cfm /healthcare/pretty-teeth
```

...as well as 100s of others.

But all of these are failing (many more than I'm showing)-

```
Redirect 301 /Dining/diningreviews/vawines.cfm /shopping/wines-2004
Redirect 301 /Dining/diningathome/carrotcake.cfm /home-garden/carrot-cake-2003
Redirect 301 /Dining/diningathome/oldvarolls.cfm /home-garden/virginia-rolls-2003
Redirect 301 /Dining/diningathome/pumpkincake.cfm /home-garden/pumpkin-cake-2003
```

The top of my .htaccess file looks like this-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#uploaded files
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-content/plugins.*
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/(.*) wp-content/blogs.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-.*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</Files>
</IfModule>

#Everything below here are Redirect 301s
```

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect says "Also, URL-path must be a fully qualified URL, not a relative path, even when used with .htaccess files or inside of <Directory> sections."

Comment: Also, on an older site, watch for Redirects that former developers may have put into httpd.conf or in other configuration files that may be interfering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont redirect statements have to include the protocol in the destination?

Comment: I don't think they have to be there.  95% of my redirects are working on this particular site

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect says "Also, URL-path must be a fully qualified URL, not a relative path, even when used with .htaccess files or inside of <Directory> sections."

Answer (score 0):

You must include the domain name in the redirect.

Never mix mod_alias and mod_rewrite directives in the same file. If you use `RewriteRule` for any of your rules, you must use `RewriteRule` (not `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch`) for ALL of your rules.

List all redirects (using `RewriteRule` syntax) before any of the rewrites (using `RewriteRule` syntax) otherwise you will inadvertently expose rewritten pointers back out on the the web as new URLs.

The code you are currently using is very very inefficient. The `.*` patterns mean your .htaccess file will attempt hundreds of thousands of "back off and retry" trial matches for every URL request hitting the server.

In particular,

`^(.\*/)?` should be replaced by `^([^/]+/)\*` in two places.

`^.\*/` should be replaced by `^/([^/]+/)\*`

`!.\*wp-content/plugins.\*` should be replaced by `!wp-content/plugins`

`^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.\*\\.php)$` should be replaced by `^([_0-9A-Z-]+/)?([^.]+\\.php)$` with the `[NC]` flag also added.

The "add a trailing slash to /wp-admin" redirect should be the very first ruleset in the file and the target URL should include the protocol and domain name. That rule should be immediately followed with a non-www to www canonicalisation rule.

The new code may well run hundreds of times quicker.